# Get MotionEvent on keyboard

Tags: android, touch, android-event

I'm looking is it possible to capture MotionEven data (pressure) on keyboard (in my app)? Or is there way to intercept all touches on screen in my app (something like full screen mode).

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
         @Override
         public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
         //for example
         if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
         }

}
```

Comment: But that would capture only touches on that particular activity, not a keyboard touches (which overlay activity).